# Rails 4 - Join Query matches all in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have two models, `Facility` and `Category`:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities
end
```

Say I have three possible `Category` records, with `name`: "Category A", "Category B", and "Category C".

I want to get all `Facility` records which are in *both* "Category A" and "Category B".

My latest query is:

```
Facility.joins(:categories).merge(Category.where(Category.arel_table[:name].matches_all(["Category A", "Category B"])))
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities" INNER JOIN "categories_facilities" ON "categories_facilities"."facility_id" = "facilities"."id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_facilities"."category_id" WHERE ("categories"."name" ILIKE 'Category A' AND "categories"."name" ILIKE 'Category B')
```

This returns no results.

Using pure Ruby (e.g. `Facility.all.select ...`), I know there is at least one `Facility` in the database which belongs to both and only both "Category A" and "Category B".

How can I perform this query either in Rails or using arel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with switching from a `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many, through`, and the following scope on `Facility`:

```
joins(:categories)
  .merge(Category.where(key: category_keys))
  .group(CategoriesFacility.arel_table[:facility_id], arel_table[:id])
  .having(CategoriesFacility.arel_table[:facility_id].count.gteq(category_keys.size))
  .uniq
```

Ideally, I'd like to still use a HABTM table, but I prefer not to write raw SQL in my code.